# How to prevent guest role access beyond login in Liferay?

Tags: security, liferay, liferay-6

We plan to implement a company-internal portal with Liferay 6.2. Since many of the team members are not within the company's network, the access has to be allowed from the internet.

Now I see a big problem with the *Guest* role, since it 1) can access Guest-viewable content without login and 2) this is the default selection when for example uploading a document.

What I really need, is that only the login page is generally viewable, but all other sites and content is only visible to logged-in users, without the need to explicitely assign the permissions for each item correctly.

So the question is, can I prevent the guest role to access anything beyond the login page, so to say eliminate it from everything within the portal?

---

Update:

It was proposed to use only private pages. While this might work, it implies as far as I know, that each user has to be member of the site. But then it's no longer possible to have a site structure with different users participating in different sites and still be able to view public infomation (meaning public for all logged-in users) - or am I wrong?

---

Update 2:

I agree to a solution where one has to prevent the assignments to the guest role programmatically, via hook or via deeper changes in liferay. Yet, I like to double-check that administrative and think of a periodic database job or program using the API which check for relations to the guest role which came in around the hook or by wrong permission settings of a user and delete them again. How could that be done?

Comment: You can have login page as public page and rest all pages as private to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a document is uploaded through a private page, the permissions actually default to be *not* accessible to "Guest". This is guaranteed easiest if you don't have any public pages.

Also, you can access the API and change the default permissions once a document gets uploaded (no need to override core Liferay functionality like defaults): Just [write a service hook](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/override-a-portal-service-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) that overrides the upload of a document with a version that sets the permissions you want right after a document has been uploaded. This will catch all other upload attempts, e.g. through services, Webdav etc.

Edit (after your comment): Added the link to Dev Guide. The actual use of the API is a bit too much to update this answer with on the fly. You might want to look at old examples like [sevencogs](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) ([part 2](https://www.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/part-ii-7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-)) to get used to the actual API, but DevGuide will describe how to write the plugin in the first place.

Comment: This might work - could you point me to a good example for it, since I'm totally unexperienced in the Liferay API...?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional information, I haven't tried it yet, but I will and thus accept this so far. Nevertheless, a related question - can I have an additional check on the database level, e.g. via periodic database job, and delete guest permissions in case they came in via some overlooked way or were somehow not correctly permitted by the hook?

Comment: Yes, sure. How to do this might be a bit too much for an add on here, but I believe that the sevencogs sample that I linked in my answer provides some introductory contact with the API

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the public pages etc. and disable the guest's `VIEW` permission on every element but the login page and it's resources.

Now, as you have already noticed, the fact that, by default, whenever creating any content the Guest gets the `VIEW` permission is a substantial problem.

I'd suggest to simply override the `<guest-defaults>` values in Liferay's core portlets' resource permission files (the ones in `ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/resource-actions/`) to remove these default values. If it's not clear to you on how to do it, see, e.g., this forum topic: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/486154 .

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is delete all public pages. Every page that you create should be private. Don't worry about login page, reset password and self-registration (if allowed), by default they are public.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But that means, every user has to be member of every site? Or can I allow those private pages for generally logged-in users and additionally have members which possibly can do more?

Comment: Yes. The default site (or another site) could be used for landing any user. And have specific sites for member users.